# BinaryStreams-like helper classes for NIO Channels?

Tags: java, nio, guava, apache-commons-io

Is there a library for NIO ByteChannel providing similar utilities to what google-guava and commons-io provide for streams? 
E.g. I'd like to have several ReadableByteChannels concatenated in one or have a view of a channel limited to a particular size.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion. How about posting a Feature Request to guava?

Comment: I've found a similar request http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=324 Anyway, I would probably have to contribute it myself :).

Answer (score 0):

You can partially work around it using the utility methods in the [Channels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html) class, e.g.

```
static byte[] toByteArray(ReadableByteChannel ch) {
    return ByteStreams.toByteArray(Channels.newInputStream(ch));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've perfromed a bit of testing and it seems that using FileChannel directly is faster than wrapping FileInputStream with this method.

Comment: I mean using guava to wrap FileInputStream and then wrapping it into Channel.